# Is there a way to import entire folder similar to file import in swift for xcode macOS project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

As we can use `.fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [.data]) { (result) in` to import a certain file, is there a way if I want to select a certain folder when prompted and then the Xcode project can read all the files in that directory?

Otherwise, if we cannot select a folder, is there a way that if we have a certain path to a folder, we can use that path to read all the files in that folder?

This is for building a macOS application using Xcode and Swift.

Comment: Did you try `UTType.folder`?